# How do I remove part of a string from a url using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

How do I remove everything before */post* in this string below and add my own address using Javascript/JQuery

```
showLogo=false&showVersionInfo=false&dataFile=/post/2653785385/photoset_xml/tumblr_lepsihc2RV1qbclqg/500
```

I want it to appear like this:

```
http://mydomain.com/post/2653785385/photoset_xml/tumblr_lepsihc2RV1qbclqg/500
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var str = 'showLogo=false&showVersionInfo=false&dataFile=/post/2653785385/photoset_xml/tumblr_lepsihc2RV1qbclqg/500';

str = 'http://mydomain.com' + str.split('&dataFile=')[1];
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/52z2z/

Here it splits the string on `'&dataFile='`, gets the last item in the resulting Array, and concatenates it do your domain.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this in Javascript using regular expressions:

```
var url = "showLogo=false&showVersionInfo=false&dataFile=/post/2653785385/photoset_xml/tumblr_lepsihc2RV1qbclqg/500";
var matches = url.match(/dataFile=(.*)/);
var what_you_need = "http://mydomain.com" + matches[1];
```

HTH